# Golang sqlx How to do NamexExec with on conflict

Tags: postgresql, go, sqlx

I'm trying to do an postgres query with an on conflict using sqlx NameExec but keep getting

```
pg: got 6 parameters but the statement requires 4
```

example code

```
    query := `INSERT INTO table_name (name, number, address, age)
      VALUES (:name, :number, :address, :age) 
      ON CONFLICT (name, number) 
      DO UPDATE SET (name, address)
      = (:age, :number)`
_, err := db.NamedExec(query, records)
```

I know it's do do with the update section, and the rest of the query works if I remove it. but I don't know how to get it to work in the way that I want it to?

for reference this is using v1.3.5 of sqlx

Answer (score 1):

The correct sqlx NameExec UPSERT syntax:

```
query := `INSERT INTO table_name (name, number, address, age)
          VALUES (:name, :number, :address, :age)
          ON CONFLICT (name, number)
          DO UPDATE SET address = excluded.address, age = excluded.age`
```

`excluded` is the special table name according to [PG doc:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#id-1.9.3.152.6.3.3)

> ...The SET and WHERE clauses in ON
> CONFLICT DO UPDATE have access to the existing row using the table's
> name (or an alias), and to the row proposed for insertion using the
> special **excluded** table.

To access the values of existing table instead:

```
    DO UPDATE SET address = table_name.address, age = table_name.age
```

Alternatively, you can do [all upserts in a single transaction](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/issues/690#issuecomment-986056178)

```
var query = `INSERT INTO table_name (name, number, address, age) 
             VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) 
             ON CONFLICT (name, number) 
             DO UPDATE SET address = $3, age = $4`
```